# How to prevent double-lunching of activity

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, android-pendingintent

My question is very simple, but I can't find the answer. The task is to lunch activity from notification, but if the activity is working, just pass data to that activity. My app just lunch activity one by another, and is's not right for me.

```
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, com.inyourcells.finelife.MainDesk.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra(MainDesk.CONFIRM_INDEX_PARAM, confirmIndex);
        pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, id, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


        builder = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.new_operation))
                .setContentText(getString(R.string.press_new_operation)+sum+MainDesk.CUR)
                .setTicker(getString(R.string.ticker_new_operation)).setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND|Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE|Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS).setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.accounts_icon);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for your Activity in Manifest:

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

Comment: I's working for to not start twice, but this method don't pass intent data to activity. If the activity is lunched, it just the intent just don't work.

Comment: I've founde onNewIntent() callback function, I'll try it. If it's ok, it's an answer